# how to not match whitespace in certain parts of a line in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a line:

```
$lines = AC   P00450; Q14063;
```

I need to use regex to match only part of the string that comes after AC. I use the following code:

```
if ($lines =~ /^AC(.*)/) {
    print $1, "\n";
}
```

and it gives me the following output:

```
   P00450; Q14063;
```

how do I adjust my regex so that it doesn't match the whitespace after AC, before P00450 and just returns me P00450; Q14063; without the whitespace in the front? I understand that I am getting my output because .* matches any type of character. That is essentially what I want but without the whitespace before P00450.

Comment: `if ($lines =~ /^AC\s+(.*)/)` ?

Comment: Is it `$line` or `$lines`? And the regex pattern you show won't match that string because `^` anchors to the start of the string and `AC` doesn't appear at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude one or more whitespaces.

```
if ($lines =~ /^AC\s+(.*)/)
```